# Как можно ли получить значение SID из Set-Cookie на Фронте?

Tags: javascript, http, cookie, axios, response

У меня поставлена задача выполнять Post запросы используя axios с фронта на сервер и при выполнении первого запроса сохранить значение SID из заголовка SetCookie передавая в последующие запросы.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно получить данное значение?

Вот что я получаю в качестве ответа.
[image: Ответ с сервера]

Почему в поле headers отсутствует set-cookie?

Значение которое мне нужно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код запроса

```
export class Services {
  constructor() {
    this._URL = 'https://lichi.com/api/cart/';
  }
  async addToCard() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(this._URL + 'add?lang=1&shop=1&id=88250');
      console.log(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак не получить.

Заголовок `Set-Cookie` входит в [список запрещённых](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name) к чтению.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.